# How to run javascript script only once and not let my forms ajax call run

Tags: javascript, html

> This is a hard question to ask but have been stuck for a long time. So i have a script that I am trying to run to check what domains are at the end of the email addresses users are entering.
>
> **My Script:**

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
```

}

```
function EmailFunction() {
var emailNames = [];
var emailDomains = [];
emailNames = $("#emailing").val();
var arrEmail = emailNames.split(', ');
console.log("Array " + arrEmail);
var len = arrEmail.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var domain = arrEmail[i].split("@").pop();
    emailDomains.push(domain)
    var unique = emailDomains.filter(onlyUnique);
    if (unique == "fmb.com") {
        swal({
            title: "Security",
            text: "* Since this is an yahoo email please make sure you are sending to the correct person and hit CONFIRM.",
            icon: "info",
            html: true,
            button: {
                text: "Confirm",
            },
        });
    }
}
console.log(unique);
```

}

> **Here is my form:**

```
<form id="myForm" name="formSubmit" method="post" action="ExportFile/">
    @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@
    <button id="resetbtn" class="resetting" >Clear </button>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.accountNum)
    <span class="error-message">@Session["Error"]</span>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="my-container">
            <p><label class="acct-text" for="AccountNumber"> Step 1 - Enter Account Number :</label></p>
            <div class="accErr"></div>
            <p><input type="text" class="form-control" name="accountNum" id="accountNum" placeholder="Account Number"></p>
            <p id="Status"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
        <p><label class="year" for="Year">Step 2 - Select Statement Year(s) :</label></p>
        <div id="checkboxes" class="grid-container">
            @{
                foreach (var year in (IEnumerable<string>)Session["years"])
                {
            <div >
                <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_1"> @year</label>
            </div>
                }
            }
        </div>
        <button id="selectionYears" class="select-all-years">Select All Years</button>

    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <p><label class="month-text">Step 3 - Select Statement(s) Month :</label></p>
        <div id="checkboxes" class="grid-container" >
                <label><input class="month" id="01" name="month" type="checkbox"> January</label>
                <label><input class="month" id="02" name="month" type="checkbox"> February</label>
                <label><input class="month" id="03" name="month" type="checkbox"> March</label>
                <label><input class="month" id="04" name="month" type="checkbox"> April</label>
                <label><input class="month" id="05" name="month" type="checkbox"> May</label>
                <label><input class="month" id="06" name="month" type="checkbox"> June</label>
                <label><input class="month" id="07" name="month" type="checkbox"> July</label>
                <label><input class="month" id="08" name="month" type="checkbox"> August</label>
                <label><input class="month" id="09" name="month" type="checkbox"> September</label>
                <label><input class="month" id="10" name="month" type="checkbox"> October</label>
                <label><input class="month" id="11" name="month" type="checkbox"> November</label>
                <label><input class="month" id="12" name="month" type="checkbox"> December</label>
        </div>
        <button id="selectionMonths" class="select-all">Select All Months</button>
    </div>

    <div class="radio-container">
        <p><label for="Delivery">Step 4 - Select Delivery Method :</label></p>

        <div class="radioErr"></div>
        <p><label><input class="form-radio" type="radio" name="radiodecision" id="download" /> Download Statements</label></p>
        <p><label><input class="form-radio" type="radio" name="radiodecision" id="email" /> Email Statements</label></p>
        <input id="emailing" name="emailMandatory" type="text" class='txbx' hidden="hidden" oninput="EmailFunction()" />
        <input id="emailing1"  name="emailMandatory1" type="text" class='txbx1' hidden="hidden" />
    </div>

    <p class="message" hidden="hidden">* To send to multiple recipients, separate the email addresses using a comma "," </p>
    <p class="message" hidden="hidden">* Statement(s) will be delivered via FMBSECURE</p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Retrieve Statements" @*onclick="EmailFunction()"*@ id="main-form-submit">
    
</form>
```

> Im finally able to get the domain names extracted from the email addresses so now i can do what i want with them. **My main issue is** when i click the submit button the code runs and my ajax call sends the info to the back end and everything just continues to run without letting the user click confirm from my pop up and then double check the email addresses. **How can I stop everything running until the user goes through this script and double checks the email addresses and then clicks the submit button to submit the form?**
>
> **My Ajax call/Submithandler**

```
$("form[name='formSubmit']").validate({
        
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            
            // Get the text values of Account Number
            var accountNumber = $("#accountNum").val();
            //console.log(accountNumber)
            
            var emailNames = [];
            //var result = emailNames.replace(/\s/g, "").split(/,|;/);
            emailNames = $("#emailing").val();
            
            // Post values to controller
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ROOT + 'Home/ExportFile',
                data: JSON.stringify({ acctNum: accountNumber, emails: emailNames }),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data.success == true && data.message == "* Your files will begin to download.")
                    {
                        swal({
                            title: "Successful Download",
                            text: data.message,
                            icon: "success",
                            html: true,
                            button: {
                                text: "Okay",
                            },
                        });

                        DownloadStatements();
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use an event listener and prevent the default form's behaviour which is send the form data and refresh the page.

```
const form = document.querySelector('#myForm');
const formSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    //This will prevent the form submission (default behaviour)
    e.preventDefault();
    //Here you can show a confirm view or modal
    if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
        //The user is sure
        //Do stuff
        //Then submit the form
        form.submit()
    }
    else return;
}
form.addEventListener('submit', formSubmitHandler)
```

More info about form events [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event).